# Access the values of the columns field

Tags: postgresql

How I can access the Column description the words "pair", "of" and "shoes" and copy them to a new table column?

```
| ID |   DESCRIPTION | PRICE |             EMAIL |
--------------------------------------------------
|  4 | pair, of, shoes |  18.4 | myemail@gmail.com |
```

Comment: Can you add an example of expected output please?

Comment: yes I want a new column named "x" with the "pair" value,  a new column named "y" with the "of" value and a new column named "z" with the "shoes" value

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE public."Test"
SET x = SPLIT_PART(DESCRIPTION, ',', 1);
```

This is what I wanted